# VerticalGridView scrolls horizontally

Tags: android, grid, android-support-library

I finally had success adding a VerticalGridView from android support library to my project.
Now the problem is the grid scrolls both horizontally and vertically!

Here is my source :

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

and java code:

```
mRecyclerView = (VerticalGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setNumColumns(4);
mRecyclerView.setVerticalMargin(24);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix this. You just have to set `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager` as the layout manager for the `VerticalGridView`, as in the following (notice that the number of columns is passed in the constructor):

```
mRecyclerView = (VerticalGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 4));
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setVerticalMargin(24);
```

Comment: I have same problem, but unfortunately, the leanback library has an empty constructor, there is no such constructor as in the support library, columns number passing with method setNumColumns(spanCount)

Comment: This will cause focused list item not bring to middle of screen.

Answer (score 0):

no matter which one you choose, you can take this list and scroll in both directions, it feels like it can be moved around the screen. There must be a way to disable scrolling in one direction

Is there a way to deal with it?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33310433)

Answer (score -1):

in leanback lib have two classes are ther 1. VerticalGridView 2.HorizontalGridView
u can use HorizontalGridView for Horizontal scroll

Comment: no matter which one you choose, you can take this list and scroll in both directions, it feels like it can be moved around the screen. There must be a way to disable scrolling in one direction